# JPA OneToMany eager fetch does not work

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

I have a weird problem with two entities with one-to-many relation in JPA. I am using Glassfish 3.1.2.2 with EclipseLink 2.3.2. This is the first entity:

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="SampleQueryGroup.findAll", query="SELECT g FROM SampleQueryGroup g")
})
@Entity
public class SampleQueryGroup implements Serializable {

    // Simple properties, including id (primary key)

    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "group",
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE}
    )
    private List<SampleQuery> sampleQueries;

    // Gettes/setters, hashcode/equals

}
```

And this is the second one:

```
@Entity
public class SampleQuery implements Serializable {

    // Simple properties, including id (primary key)

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private SampleQueryGroup group;

    // Gettes/setters, hashcode/equals

}
```

I have a stateless session bean which uses an injected `EntityManager` to run `SampleQueryGroup.findAll` named query. I also have a CDI managed bean which calls the SSB method and iterates through `SampleQueryGroup.getSampleQueries()` for each `SampleQueryGroup` returned by the method. I didn't paste the code as it is pretty straightforward and somehow standard for any Java EE application.

The problem is the eager fetch does not work and `getSampleQueries()` returns an empty list. However, when I change the fetch type back to FetchType.LAZY, everything works and I get the list correctly populated. I don't understand why this happens. Does it have anything to do with internal caching mechanisms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that when you add a new SampleQuery you are not adding it to the SampleQueryGroup sampleQueries, so when you access it, it is not their.  When it is LAZY you do not trigger it until you have inserted the SampleQuery, so then it is there.

You need to maintain both sides of your relationships. (you could also disable caching, or refesh the object, but your code would still be broken).

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Object_corruption.2C_one_side_of_the_relationship_is_not_updated_after_updating_the_other_side

Comment: Thank you James, I think that was the problem. In a method of a SSB which persists the entities, is it necessary to explicitly set/add each entity to the other one?